# Escape Characters in Regex sub of Markdown Links to HTML Links

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert markdown of something like:

```
[Board Management](Boards/boardManagement.md)
```

to something like this using Python:

```
<a href='#' onclick='requestPage("Boards/boardManagement.md");'>Board Management</a>
```

I've found code for a re.sub as follows, but the only way I can get it to work is to not include any type of quotes around requestPage and the browser seems to automatically put them in...

```
 filteredPage = re.sub('\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)', r"<a href='#' onclick=requestPage('\2');>\1</a>", pageContent)
```

where pageContent is the markdown.  Though it seems to work, it would seem best to not depend upon the browser to do the autoinsertion, but everytime I try to rewrite it with the quotes in, it doesn't produce the correct results.  For example,

```
filteredPage = re.sub('\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)', r"<a href='#' onclick=\"requestPage('\2');\">\1</a>", pageContent)
```

results in

```
<a href="#" onclick=\"requestPage('Boards/boardManagement.md');\">Board Management</a>
```

Is there a way to accomplish the desired link with quotes around the onclick function, other than depending upon the browser to do it?

Comment: The most general solution is probably to look at the many existing Python Markdown implementations and find one that supports the `onclick` attribute. For example, Python-Markdown has an [attribute lists](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/) extension.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was able to take your suggestion and make it work.  However, I would prefer not to decorate the markdown documents with the html attributes.  The markdown comes from github pages documents that I'm trying to serve, a certain way, from within a python application.  I would prefer to do all the processing in the python application itself and not depend upon a contributor getting all the decorations correct.  I can go with my current solution above, but just want to know if there is a way to do the quotes within quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary

The problem you're having is that when you escape a quote in a raw string literal (`r"..."`), the backslash is not removed from the string. To see what I mean, look at what this code outputs:

```
print( "abc \" def")  # abc " def    (the backslash is gone)
print(r"abc \" def")  # abc \" def   (the backslash is in the string)
```

In most cases, the solution is to use a triple-quoted string:

```
print( """abc \" def""") # abc " def   (this is the same as the first one)
print(r"""abc " def""" ) # abc " def   (this is how to get quotes in a raw string)
```

So your code becomes this:

```
re.sub(r'\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)',
       r"""<a href='#' onclick="requestPage('\2');">\1</a>""",
       pageContent)
```

Another option would be to use `'` for your string, and put the `href` attribute in `"`: you could have something like `r'<a href="#" onclick="request...">'`.

## Explanation

The key to understanding how raw string literals work may be this: **if you use a backslash in a raw string literal, it will be included in the string.**

Raw string literals are only *mostly* raw. The one exception is quotations. This lets you include quotation marks in your string. But unlike a regular string, if you escape a quotation in a raw string literal, the backslash will still be in the string.

This is specified in the last paragraph of [the section on string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote

The solution to your problem is to use a triple-quoted raw string literal and not escape the quote, as shown above.

In more extreme cases, you can use [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) to help with escaping strings, but this probably isn't a good use case for it. I'd only use it if (a) the string needed to contain both `"""` and `'''`, or (b) I was already using string literal concatenation for another reason (like splitting a long string across multiple lines).

---

And one last thing: You should be using raw string literals for your regular expressions. It isn't *necessary* for the regex you have here, but it makes it much easier to write (and read) regular expressions, because every backslash is always in the string, so you get to read exactly what the regex engine will read.

More importantly, unrecognized escape sequences (which include `\(` and `\[`) are being phased out and will eventually raise a `SyntaxError`, so if you want your code to keep working in as many future versions of Python as possible, put your regular expressions in raw literals.

Comment: I'm still confused, but I broke up the string into a bunch of smaller strings and used the string literal concatenation to piece it together.  It works and that's what matters:

Comment: @madgrizzle I've added a summary section and generally reworded a lot of the answer to try to make it clearer and more focused. I've also included an actual solution for you (please don't use string literal concatenation for this, it's very hard to read).

Comment: Thank you very much.  That clarified it for me (obvious to me now what you meant).  As for your parting words regarding phasing out of unrecognized escape sequences, can you point me somewhere to read up on that?

Comment: @madgrizzle It's the notice just before the last paragraph of [Section 2.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Once that change happens, only the escape sequences in the tables in Section 2.4.1 will be allowed. This process started with [this Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue27364), which contains the discussion of why they're doing it (and some of the first messages link to earlier discussions).